# How to use AT Commands instead of Java Wireless Messaging API (WMA), for SMS to PORT

Tags: java, sms, sms-gateway, at-command

I need to know How to use AT Commands instead of Java Wireless Messaging API (WMA) to send SMS to specific port.

Anyone have one good example?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 1):

[GSM 07.05](http://www.ctiforum.com/standard/standard/etsi/0705.pdf) might be what you’re after. From the first chapter, “Scope:”

> This Global System for Mobile communications Technical Specification (GTS) defines three interface
>   protocols for control of SMS functions within a GSM mobile telephone from a remote terminal via an
>   asynchronous interface.
>
> […]
>
> Clause 3 defines a character-based interfaced based on “AT” commands (“Text Mode”). This mode is
>   suitable for unintelligent terminals or terminal emulators, and for application software built on command
>   structures like those defined in V.25ter. Some of the commands defined in clause 3 will also be useful for
>   implementations of clause 2 and/or clause 4, for example enabling an indication of incoming SMS
>   messages.

The rest is just communication with a serial port (or TCP connection in case of larger GSM modem farms that are connected via terminal servers) in which case you also want to take a look at the [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html).

Comment: Thanks, do you know where can I get the source of the Java Wireless Messaging API (WMA)?